# Ethernet shield reset problems

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I know there are multiple threads about ethernet shields not starting properly after power up and that there are versions that don't have those problems. But which versions are okay? Which versions do not require extra soldering/pin bending/physical resets?

How good are chinese rip-offs of those versions?

Comment: Does the Ethernet shield also have an SD? In that case check that the chip select pins are disabled in the setup().

Comment: It does have a SD card slot, but I don't use sd card at the moment.

Comment: This might be of some help. http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=25634.0

Comment: Yep I checked it, but I'm still looking for a way that doesn't include bending pins, extra soldering or extra code. If you look at the #41 comment in the link you posted, should that work? What about #48, what version is that?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with Ethernet Shields and modules. Most of them has reset issue. So I just put a 100nF Capacitor between the reset pin and ground pin. This solution works for most of the time.

This issue is there because the IC on board the shield does not have the power on reset option.

You can also tie the reset pin of your module with the reset pin of the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make any modifications to the shield, and you don't want to make any modifications in code, then there really is only one option:

- Don't use cheap knockoffs, but buy a genuine Arduino one.

If you have a board that requires modifications to work properly and if you're unwilling to make those required modifications then you can not just magic it into working by waving your magic wand.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that the same thing is happening on the original version of arduino shield. I want to buy another original, but there is no way of me buying it if the same problem will happen again.